# sed: can't read ../../build.gradle: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, git, gradle, sed

I am new to git and github. I am working on a project where I need to commit my changes to github repository in a specific branch.
But I am getting the error

```
$ git commit

3.5.0.1
s/3.5.0.1/3.5.1.1/g
sed: can't read ../../build.gradle: No such file or directory
```

I have also attached the pre-commit file code here.

```
#!/bin/sh

## finding the exact line in the gradle file
#ORIGINAL_STRING=$(cat ../../build.gradle | grep -E '\d\.\d\.\d\.\d')
## extracting the exact parts but with " around
#TEMP_STRING=$(echo $ORIGINAL_STRING | grep -Eo '"(.*)"')
## the exact numbering scheme
#FINAL_VERSION=$(echo $TEMP_STRING | sed 's/"//g') # 3.5.0.1

#Extract APK version
v=$(cat build.gradle  | grep rtVersionName | awk '{print $1}')
FINAL_VERSION=$(echo ${v} | cut -d"\"" -f2)
echo ${FINAL_VERSION}

major=0
minor=0
build=0
assets=0

regex="([0-9]+).([0-9]+).([0-9]+).([0-9]+)"
if [[ $FINAL_VERSION =~ $regex ]]; then
 major="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
 minor="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
 build="${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
 assets="${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
fi

# increment the build number
build=$(echo $build + 1 | bc)
NEW_VERSION="${major}.${minor}.${build}.${assets}"


SED_ARGUMENT=$(echo "s/${FINAL_VERSION}/${NEW_VERSION}/g")
echo $SED_ARGUMENT

sed -i -e `printf $SED_ARGUMENT` ../../build.gradle
```

The error comes in the last line of this file basically. I am using windows.
Things I tried:

```
sed -i -e `printf $SED_ARGUMENT` ../../build.gradle



sed -i ' ' -e `printf $SED_ARGUMENT` ../../build.gradle
```

I am unable to understand where am I actually doing wrong. Kindly help me out.

Comment: With such relative references, you cannot `git commit` from anywhere in the repository.

Comment: I did git commit in the folder where I wanted to make change.Apart from this, I tried it doing using android studio as well.

Comment: Who put this particular `sed` command into this particular pre-commit hook? Ask them why they use `../../build.gradle` here. There's probably some other setup you've skipped, that's required to use this particular pre-commit hook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed: can't read ../../build.gradle: No such file or directory
```

This one is rather simple. Your `build.gradle` file is not at `../../build.gradle`.

The solution is to determine actual path to the `build.gradle` file relative to the script, and change the path in the script.

To debug this, do `echo Current Directory: $PWD` in the script to see what the actual working directory is, then you should be able to determine the correct path to use.